# Dovecot create mbox type mailboxes even it shouldn't

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I'm almost in finished task, but devecot always create mbox type mailbox for users even I've configured to use maildir syntax.

I'm using dovecot, postfix, postfixadmin and MySQL in my server.

Snippet from `10-mail.conf`

```
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
```

#### edit:

mailbox are created trough postfixadmin

Answer (score 1):

Seems to that I postfix can't find or access proper auth socket:

*warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: Connection refused*

10-master.conf:

```
service auth {   
     unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth { 
         mode = 0666
         user = root
         group = root
     }

    # Auth process is run as this user.   
    #user = $default_internal_user
}
```

and `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
```

Comment: This fixed it:   unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0666
    user = root
    group = root
 }

Answer (score 0):

You also have to configure the delivery agent (LDA) to use the same format and location unless you explicitly use dovecot-lda as delivery agent. Otherwise Postfix delivers to mbox and dovecot reads from Maildir.

So either use

```
home_mailbox = /var/mail/vhosts/
```

or use dovecot-lda:

```
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/dovecot-lda -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"
```

or whereever dovecot is placed on your system.

Comment: No luck. maillog contains : Oct  7 00:29:37 master postfix/qmgr[29446]: 69AC45120A53: from=<someadmin@gmail.com>, size=310, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  7 00:29:37 master postfix/qmgr[29446]: warning: connect to transport private/dovecot: Connection refused
Oct  7 00:29:37 master postfix/qmgr[29446]: C898C5120A52: from=<someadmin@gmail.com>, size=301, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Oct  7 00:29:37 master postfix/error[29451]: C898C5120A52: to=<teppo7@server.com>, relay=none, delay=925, delays=925/0/0/0.06, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (mail transport unavailable)